# Need Power mockito compatible maven dependency version with existing Mockito maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am using below Mockito maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
     <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.10.19</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>mockrunner</groupId>
     <artifactId>mockrunner-jca</artifactId>
     <version>0.4.2-j2ee5-jdk1.6</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.mockrunner</groupId>
     <artifactId>mockrunner-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>0.4.2-j2ee5-jdk1.6</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.mockejb</groupId>
     <artifactId>mockejb</artifactId>
     <version>0.6-beta2</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Can anyone suggest which Power Mockito maven dependency I need to use which is compatible with above dependency?

i am getting below error when i use below Powe Mockito dependency:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
     <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId> 
     <version>1.6.6</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>         
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2 -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
     <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId> 
     <version>1.6.6</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>         
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-testng -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
     <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId> 
     <version>1.6.6</version>
<scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/plugins/MockMaker$TypeMockability
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.<init>(PowerMockMaker.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using such an old version of mockito? Also using such old dependency like `com.mockrunner:*:0.4.2-j2ee5-jdk1.6` (ca. 15 years old)  Powermock? Why?

Comment: that dependency has been used in my project. Can you suggest better version for mockito and powermockito?

Comment: its a legacy project

Comment: First which JDK do you use and which Maven version do you use?  I expected that it's an legacy project... but using 15 years old stuff... Phew... unfortunately I can not suggest better versions for that... you have to check the release notes etc. and find matching versions...